# Points and real intervals

Tags: real-analysis, philosophy, paradoxes

The sorites paradox goes like this: Start with a heap of sand. Remove a grain of sand and you still have a heap; remove another, and another, and another, and you'll still have a heap. Eventually, though, your heap will be appreciably smaller, and eventually you'll be left with a single grain of sand. So, when exactly did we go from heap to non-heap?

My question is about the real line. (It's not quite the same problem as the sorites paradox, but it's similar enough for the paradox to be illustrative.)

How do we make the move from a dimensionless point to an open interval on the real line (apparently nothing more than a concatenation of dimensionless points) that can be use as measurement? Don't get me wrong: I'm not saying that we start with a point on the real line, then add the "next" one, and ask when it becomes an interval. And I'm not saying that we begin, as with the sorites, with an open interval and successively remove points until we're left (after uncountably many years have passed) with a single point, and ask when the interval became a non-interval.

But in the same way that there's a qualitative (but ambiguous) different between heaps and non-heaps, so there's a difference between points and intervals. How is it that dimensionless points strung together become a one-dimensional interval? And the fact that an open interval of the real line can't be constructed by concatenating points makes the affair seem even more whimsical: instead, intervals are "constructed" by taking two unequal points, considering the span between them (perhaps including the points, as well), and then declaring, by fiat, "Yep--there's an interval there!"

Apologies is this has been asked before. I couldn't find where it had.

Comment: This is a question of philosophy, not of math. Nobody has a good answer as to how a big pile of dimensionless points suddenly develops a dimension. In measure theory they sidestep the question by requiring only countable additivity. That's an implicit acknowledgement that there's no sensible answer to the question of how an uncountable set of points turns into a line or a region. It's just the way it is.

Comment: Thanks! If the answer is we don't know, at least I know we don't know, and I can let the question alone. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's not quite the same thing, since intervals have a very specific property: If $x$ and $y$ are in the interval and $z$ lies between $x$ and $y$, then $z$ is in the interval as well.

This means that if the interval is open, removing any point would make it no longer an interval. If you removed $1$ from $(0,2)$ you get the union of two intervals, but you don't get an interval.

You might ask, instead, at which point we don't have a set which contains an interval? But then we can just remove all the rational number, or some other countable dense set, then resulting set, $(0,2)\setminus\Bbb Q$ does not contain any interval, since any interval must have a rational number in it. And this process only takes $\aleph_0$ years to complete.

The heap paradox uses the fact that a heap is discrete, and removing a single point does not chain its features very much. Intervals of real numbers don't have this property, and removing a point changes them very much. The question, if you want to transfer it to higher cardinalities, should be asked, perhaps, on a set which looks more like the irrational numbers, or even the rational numbers. But even then, you might want to readjust the notion of "heap" to be something more suitable, rather than just "interval".

Comment: I'm sorry--I understand there are substantive differences between the two. I only meant to use the sorites to illustrate the ambiguities between $p$ and non-$p$--heaps of sand and non-heaps of sand, intervals composed of points and points themselves.

Comment: But my question is the same, and hasn't been answered--how is it that an interval having dimension can be composed of points having no dimension? That's my question.

Comment: So your question is how can a set is the union of singletons?

Comment: I think user4894 just answered it above. I thought the answer might be that there's no answer, but I thought I'd ask just the same.

Comment: I can't agree with "there's no answer"; particularly because it seems that I don't quite understand what you're trying to ask. And from the looks of it, I'm not quite sure that you do either.

Comment: I mean, the question is simple. I've asked it multiple times now. How does a concatenation of dimensionless points compose an interval having dimension? How do we go from no dimension to some dimension, simply by stringing together objects of no dimension? And I see that user4894 is right--this isn't a mathematically tractable question. If I could, I'd delete the question.

Comment: So you *are* in fact asking how can a set be equal to the union of the singletons it contains.

Comment: Humbleness and accuracy compel me to note that you should believe what @Asaf says around here more than you should believe anything I say. :-)

Comment: @user4894: Hah, thanks for the support, I suppose. (Also, as far as pinging users go, you might be better off pinging Ryan, not me. I get notified anyway since it's a comment on my answer.)

Comment: I'm not impugning anyone's knowledge. It would be completely absurd for me to do that. But I don't know that the question, "How can a set be equal to the union of its singetons" is equivalent to "How we construct something having dimension when its components have no dimension." I'm guessing they're not the same, and that, like you said, this isn't a mathematically tractable question. Thank you both for your insights.

Comment: @Ryan: I spent the last ten minutes writing and rewriting this answer, because it seems to me that you're really asking a question about the foundation of the real numbers. The issue is that we're not "constructing them by hand". Instead we just "take them for granted" when we study analysis or whatever. We can justify their existence and construct the set, but we don't do it by sticking one point after another, instead we use other methods to define and prove the existence of $\Bbb R$ with their linear order. [...]

Comment: [...] Sticking the points together is the same as claiming that $(0,1)=\bigcup_{x\in(0,1)}\{x\}$. We just add one after another; even if this is not quite an organized process of doing one thing, then another. Assuming the axiom of choice we can ensure that $\Bbb R$ can be well-ordered, in which case we can in fact make this into a well-ordered process, where each step has a successive step. But that's not the issue here. The point I'm trying to make is that the "creation" of the interval is not from the points per se. It's a different process.

Comment: (And since I couldn't quite organize my thoughts into this, I didn't save the edits I made to the answer.)